# Android Navigation Component and File Chooser

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I am using Android Navigation with two fragments "Fragment A" and "Fragment B"

In "Fragment A" I open "Fragment B":

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_fragmenta_to_fragmentb)
```

In "Fragment B" I open a file chooser with startActivityForResult:

```
val openFileIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT)
openFileIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_OPENABLE)
openFileIntent.type = "application/json"
val mimeTypes = arrayOf("application/octet-stream")
openFileIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimeTypes)
        
startActivityForResult(
   Intent.createChooser(
   openFileIntent,
   getString(R.string.load_from_file)), 909)
```

In "Fragment B" when a file has been selected I receive a onActivityResult as expected:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) { 
   //Do something with data from the file
}
```

What I do not understand is that I am now seeing "Fragment A" displayed instead of staying in "Fragment B". Am I doing something wrong or is this an issue when using Navigation Component with startActivityForResult? Do anyone have a fix to make the app stay in the fragment where startActivityForResult was called? I have a hard time finding documentation about integrating Navigation Component with Intents that starts processes outside the app (ie. file chooser, caller app).

Comment: Navigation always saves your state exactly where were, whether you call `startActivityForResult()` and come back to your app, whether you use 'Don't keep activities' and hit the home button, etc. Sounds like something else you're doing is popping your Fragment B off the back stack (since if you get `onActivityResult()`, it was still on the back stack when you returned from `startActivityForResult()`).

Comment: @ianhanniballake  You were completely right. Outside the two fragments I was listening to some events and programmatically navigated to fragment A. I was just too focused on something being wrong in the navgation framework - Thank you very much for your hint!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As hinted in Ians comment on my question I listened to some events in the main activity and programmatically navigated to "Fragment A" under some circumstances. After removing this navigation the app stays in "Fragment B" after picking a file as I would expect.